# How to handle different reference directions in database and ZF2 application?

Tags: zend-framework2, nested, zend-form, zend-form-element, formcollection

`Zend\Form\Fieldset`s and `Zend\Form\Collections`s can be nested and provide a very comfortable way to map complex object structures to them, in order to get a comlete object (ready to be saved) from the form input more or less automatically. The [**Form Collections tutorial**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html) provides a very good example.

The case I'm currently having is a bit more complex, since it contains a reference inversion. That means:

I have two entities -- `MyA` and `MyB` and while in the database the relationship between them is implemented as `FOREIGN KEY` from `myb.mya_id` to `mya.id`, the application is using an inverted referencing:

```
MyA has MyB
```

Or with some code:

```
namespace My\DataObject;

class MyA {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    /*
     * @var text
     */
    private $foo;
    /**
     * @var MyB
     */
    private $myB;
}

namespace My\DataObject;

class MyB {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    /*
     * @var text
     */
    private $bar;
    /*
    Actually it's even bidirectional, but it's not crucial for this issue.
    For this problem it's not important,
    wheter the class MyB has a property of type MyA.
    We get the issue already,
    when we define a property of type MyB in the class MyA.
    Since the direction of the reference MyA.myB->MyB differes
    from the direction of the reference my_b.my_a.id->my_a.id.
    */

    /**
     * @var MyA
     */
    // private $myA;
}
```

My `Mapper` objects get `DataObject`s passed as argument: `MyAMapper#save(MyA $object)` and `MyBMapper#save(MyB $object)`.

```
namespace My\Mapper;
use ...
class MyAMapper
{
    ...
    public fuction save(MyA $object)
    {
        // save the plain MyA propertis a new entry in the my_a table
        ...
        $myMapperB->save($myA->getMyB());
    }
}

namespace My\Mapper;
use ...
class MyBMapper
{
    ...
    public fuction save(MyB $object)
    {
        // save the plain MyB propertis a new entry in the my_b table
        ...
    }
}
```

That means, the `MyAMapper#save(...)` has evrything needed to save the `MyA` object to the `my_a` table. But in the `MyBMapper` the data for `my_b.my_a_id` will be missing.

And I also cannot create a fieldset `MyAFieldset` with a nested fieldset `MyBFieldset` and then nest the fieldset `MyBFieldset` into `MyAFieldset` in order to fill `MyA#MyB#MyA` (in order to pass the data for `my_b.my_a_id` to `MyBMapper#save(...)`):

```
class MyAFieldset {
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'my_b',
        'type' => 'My\Form\Fieldset\MyBFieldset',
        'options' => []
    ]);
}

class MyBFieldset {
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'my_a',
        'type' => 'My\Form\Fieldset\MyAFieldset',
        'options' => []
    ]);
}
```

This would cause a recursive dependency and cannot work.

**How to handle a case, when the reference direction on the application level differs from it's direction in the database? How to create though a fieldsets structure, that provides a complete ("ready to be saved") object?**

---

**Workaround 1**

When the form is processed, a further `MyA` object can be created and added to the `MyB` object got from the form:

```
class MyConrtoller {
    ...
    public function myAction() {
        $this->myForm->bind($this->myA);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $this->myForm->setData($request->getPost());
        // here the hack #start#
        $this->myB->setMyA($this->myA);
        // here the hack #stop#
        $this->myAService->saveMyA($this->myA);
    }
}
```

Well, maybe not in the controller, the mapper might be a better place for that:

```
class MyAMapper
{
    ...
    public function save(MyA $myA)
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['foo'] = [$myA->getFoo()];
        // common saving stuff #start#
        $action = new Insert('my_a');
        $action->values($data);
        $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $newId = $result->getGeneratedValue()
        // common saving stuff #stop#
        ...
        // hack #start#
        if(! $myA->getB->getA()) {
            $myA->getB->setA(new MyA());
            $myA->getB->getA()->setId($newId);
        }
        // hack #stop#
        // and only after all that we can save the MyB
        $myB = $this->myBMapper->save($myB);
        $myA->setMyB($myB);
        ...
    }
}
```

But anyway it's just a hack.

**Workaround 2**

The `MyB` class gets a property `$myAId`. But it's also not a clean way.

**Workaround 3**

The `MyBFieldset` gets a `MyAFieldsetFake` as sub-fieldset. This fieldset class is then just a "shallow" copy of the `MyAFieldset`, that contains only the `ID` for the `MyA` data object:

```
class MyAFieldset {
    ...
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'id',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'foo',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
    }
}
class MyAFieldset {
    ...
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'id',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'bar',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'foo',
            'type' => 'My\Form\Fieldset\MyAFakeFieldset',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
    }
}
class MyAFieldset {
    ...
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'id',
            'options' => [...],
        ]);
    }
}
```

But fake objects are a bit dirty as well.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the complexity correctly, because the reverse inversion in the database, in my opinion does not affect object relationship. If you can read about doctrine, where every relationship has a owning side and an inverse side, to indicate the actual database relationship. A clean implementation in my opinion, is how you see the object relationsip. Since myA has myB, myA can be chosen to save the objects, both myA and myB.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Actually I didn't explain an important mental step. Just updated the question. Do understand the problem now?

Comment: When you set B's reference inside A, the same setter can set B's reference for A as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new table to handle the mappings on their own. Then you can isolate that complexity away from the objects that take advantage of them.

So, you could have a new object AtoBMappings

```
namespace My\DataObject;

class MyA {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
    /*
     * @var text
     */
    private $foo;
    /**
     * @var MyAtoB
     */
    private $myAtoB;
}

namespace My\DataObject;

class MyB {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var AtoBMapperID
     */
    private $myAtoB;
}

class MyAtoBMapper {
   /**
    * @var myB
    */
   private $myB

  /** 
   * @var myA
   **
   private $myA
}
```

Then, instead of hacking your Mapper method, you can simply make an assignment in MyA to MyB creation.

```
class MyAMapper
{
    ...
    public function save(MyA $myA)
    {

        $myAtoB = new MyAtoBMapper();
        //.... instert new myAtoB into DB 

        $data = [];
        $data['foo'] = [$myA->getFoo()];
        $data['myAtoB'] = $myAtoB->getId();
        // common saving stuff #start#
        $action = new Insert('my_a');
        $action->values($data);
        $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $newId = $result->getGeneratedValue();
        $myA->setMyAtoB($newAtoB);
        $myAtoBMapper->myA = $newId;
        // common saving stuff #stop#
        // and only after all that we can save the MyB
        $myB = $this->myBMapper->save($myB);
        $myB->setMyAtoB($newAtoB);
        $myAtoBMapper->myB = $myB;
        ...
    }
}
```

Do you think this would work, or do you think this is too much of a hack?